How should we tag music ID questions, considering that [identify-this-song] and [soundtrack] both exist?
I've been thinking about our music ID tagging, given the existence of both the identify-this-song tag and the soundtrack tag. I've recently asked if we should use [identify-this-actor] for character identification, as its tag wiki suggests, and the top-voted answer stated that the character tag would suffice for all character-related queries, including identification.
With the upcoming restoration of closed and deleted ID questions by the CMs, we're likely to see an influx of music ID questions. It's worth noting that despite the 2018 ID questions purge, a good number of music ID questions have managed to survive, unlike their movie and TV show counterparts (probably because they didn't have an ID tag).
Currently, we're using two tags for music identification: identify-this-song and soundtrack. The soundtrack tag, according to its wiki, covers "questions related to sound and music recorded for a motion picture or television show." Most music identification questions I've come across use the soundtrack tag rather than identify-this-song. (identify-this-song is a relatively new addition, created by another user on 2024-10-13, and is only present in 10 questions at the moment.)
This situation makes me wonder if we should head in the same direction as the character tag – using soundtrack as a catch-all for any sound or music-related questions, including identification.
So, what's the best way forward? Should we stick with identify-this-song for music identification questions? If so, should we use it alongside soundtrack or on its own?
Watched/Ignored Tags list
Should we follow the precedent set by the character tag and simply use soundtrack for all music-related questions, including identification?
If we use soundtrack for all questions about movie/TV music, including ID, users interested specifically in music ID won't be able to add the ID tag to their "Watched Tags" list. Similarly, users who don't want to see ID questions won't be able to filter them out via the "Ignored Tags" list. They'd have to either watch or ignore all music-related questions, which isn't ideal.
How should we handle identify-this-song given the presence of soundtrack and the fact that we don't use identify-this-character for character identification?
It'd be great if we could find a way to keep our tagging system consistent while ensuring it's intuitive for users.

A downvote on a meta question can be seen as disagreement with the post as per your comments you are posting since last few months.

@AJ I get why my answer might be DVed, but I'm confused about the DVs on the question itself. Does this mean that the DVers want to maintain the current approach to the [identify-this-song] tag?

I created the tag because there were a bunch of "identify this song" questions on my homepage, and I filter out ID questions. I would be happy with a generic "identify-this" tag with an additional tag for context (e.g. "prop" or "soundtrack" etc.), as long as I can use the "identify-this" tag to ignore such questions.

@BCdotWEB That's precisely why I started this discussion. We need a way for users to customize their feeds regarding ID questions. Some folks suggest lumping them with non-ID questions, but that leaves no way to filter them out.

I wouldn't suggest using identify-this-song
Using identify-this-song will encourage asking random questions about songs unrelated to movies/TV shows. If you know the movie name, you can find about the music/song as it is usually listed on IMDb, Wikipedia etc.
As I see it, if you have a question about music/song of a movie/TV show, the soundtrack should be sufficient.

A disadvantage of using [soundtrack] for all questions music-related, including ID, is that it removes the option for users to specifically watch or ignore music ID questions as per their Watched/Ignored tags preference. They'd have to watch or ignore all music-related questions, which is inconvenient. Also, I don't see how [identify-this-song] would encourage off-topic questions. Any off-topic music questions can be easily closed, just as we do with other off-topic questions. Its main function would be to specifically categorize music ID requests within our movie/TV scope.

Frankly we don't get many ID-Song questions so I'd prefer NOT to have a separate tag for them. Unfortunately, we'd start to get into diverging ID questions like "ID this prop" etc. We already have tags for most things I don't see the need to start having ID-x tags other than those we already have.

@Paulie_D The reason we didn't get many song ID questions (or any ID questions) was obviously because they're being closed as off-topic and deleted. Once the CMs restore ID questions, we'll likely see several more of them. Also, a cursory Google search reveals that a significant number have survived the 2018 ID questions purge.

Continue using the identify-this-song tag to allow users to add it to their Watched/Ignored Tags list.
We should maintain a separate identification tag for music, just as we do for other on-topic ID questions like for movies, TV shows, episodes, and actors. Music identification doesn't need to be an exception to this practice.
Using soundtrack for all music-related questions, including identification requests, as suggested in another answer, has a significant drawback. It would prevent users from specifically watching or ignoring music ID questions in their Watched/Ignored tags preferences. As you've probably noticed from our numerous meta discussions on the topic, ID questions aren't everyone's cup of tea. If we lump all music-related questions under one tag,
we would restrict users' ability to customize their feed, as they couldn't specifically watch or ignore music ID questions.
By keeping identify-this-song as a separate tag, we give users more control over the content they see. This approach aligns with our tagging system for other ID questions and maintains consistency across the site. It also respects the diverse preferences of our community members, allowing those who enjoy music ID questions to easily find them, while others can filter them out if they choose.

I'm absolutely in favor of this, precisely because of the reasons laid out here. I don't want to see questions about song identification, whereas I'm happy to see questions that ask about aspects of the soundtrack. ID questions should include a tag that indicates they are ID questions, so they can be filtered by those who don't want to see them. If people don't want tags that are too specific, fine: create a general "identify-this" one and then use "soundtrack" etc. to specify, but don't abuse the "soundtrack" for ID questions.
